# Lemma 4.11 from Varadhan's Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

$X$ is a countable space with each singleton measurable. Let $\pi(x,\cdot)$ be a transition probability giving a time-homogeneous Markov process.
We also have the powers
$$
\pi^{(n)}(a,b):= \sum_c \pi(c,b)\pi^{(n-1)}(a,c)
$$
which roughly represent the probability of going from $a$ to $b$ in $n$ steps.
We pick an initial point $x\in X$ and use the transition matrix to obtain a probability space $(X^{\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}, P_x)$.
We have Lemma 4.11 from the book/[notes](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch4.pdf)

**Lemma 4.11** If for a (not necessarily irreducible) chain starting from $x$, the probability of ever visiting $y$ is positive, then so is the probability of visiting $y$ before returning to $x$.

**Proof.**  Assume that for the chain starting from $x$ the probability of visiting
$y$ before returning to $x$ is zero. *But when it returns to $x$ it starts afresh and so* will not visit $y$ until it returns again. This reasoning can be repeated and so the chain
will have to visit $x$ infinitely often before visiting $y$. But this will use up all the
time and so it cannot visit $y$ at all.

**Question 1:** What does the italicized text mean (mathematically)? I realize that
$$
P_x(\{x\}\times\{x_1\}\times \dots\times\{x_n\}\times X \times \dots) = \pi(x,x_1)\dots\pi(x_{n-1},x_n)
$$
and that
$$P_x(X\times \dots \times \{x\}\times \{x_{n+1}\}\times\dots \times \{x_{n+k}\}\times X\times \dots ) = \pi^{(n)}(x,x)\pi(x,x_{n+1})\dots \pi(x_{n+k-1}, x_{n+k}).$$

**Question 2:** From the italicized text and the above observation, are we implicitly making the assumption that $\pi^{(n)}(x,x)>0$ for some $n$? This seems to come from irreducibility which we don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we start the process from $x$. Let $\tau_i$ be the $i$th return time to $x$, and $\sigma$ be the first time such that $y$ is hit. For convenience, define $\tau_0 = 0$. I'll assume that $y \neq x$.

The lemma is saying that if $P(\sigma < \infty) > 0$, then it also follows that $P(\sigma < \tau_1) > 0.$

---

For the proof, the idea is that the $\tau_n$ form a partition of the time axis (up to degeneracy induced by them possibly becoming infinite after a point).But then \begin{align} P(\sigma < \infty) &= \sum_{n \ge 1} P(\tau_{n-1} < \sigma < \tau_n) \\ &=\sum_{n \ge 1} P(\sigma < \tau_n|\sigma > \tau_{n-1}) P(\sigma > \tau_{n-1})\\ & = P(\sigma < \tau_1) \sum_{n \ge 1} P(\sigma > \tau_{n-1}),\end{align} where we've used the Markov property (and the fact that the process is at $x$ at each of the times $\tau_n$) to argue $$P(\sigma < \tau_n | \sigma> \tau_{n-1}) = P(\sigma < \tau_1 | \sigma > \tau_0) = P(\sigma < \tau_1).$$ So, if $P(\sigma < \tau_1) = 0$, then $P(\sigma < \infty) = 0$, contradicting the assumption.

---

This doesn't require the chain to be irreducible (or even $x$ to be recurrent). In fact, if $P(\tau_1 < \infty) = 0,$ then the result is trivial, since $P(\sigma < \tau_1) = P(\sigma < \infty)$ in this case.

Also, in my opinion, the proof as written in the question is strongly preferable - all this notation is not really needed to convey the idea, and might even obscure it somewhat. Nevertheless, it's probably a useful exercise to write it out more formally.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. According to the Lemma, aren't we trying to show that there is some $n$ such that $P\{\omega : \sigma(\omega) < \tau_n(\omega) < \infty \}>0$? This in turn implies that $P\{\omega : \tau_1 (\omega) < \infty\} >0 $ is part of the conclusion?

Comment: I'm thinking about the part of the lemma that says *returning to* $x$.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. The lemma says visiting $y$ before returning to $x$ - so it could be that one never returns to $x$. Certainly, $P(\tau_1 < \infty) > 0$ cannot be part of the conclusion - for instance consider the deterministic chain on the naturals that increments the state by $1$ at each time step, and take $x = 1,y>1.$ That said, perhaps there is some room for over-interpretation in the statement, and it could be tightened...

Comment: Maybe the proof itself could help this by first saying something like "Suppose $x$ never recurs - then the statement it trivial. If it recurs with positive probability but the probability of visiting $y$ before $x$ is $0$, then (continue the rest)". Do you think this would help clarify things?

Comment: I'm happy to take your interpretation for the Lemma. And in this case your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks, +1. I still don't like the language in the book though.

Comment: And thanks for that example as well.